# Java - Thread.sleep VS Awaitility.await()

Tags: java, awaitility

I'd like to replace `Thread.sleep` with `Awaitility.await()`,ideally with minimal changes, as I'm going over Sonar bugs in an older repository. I'm attempting to avoid usage of `until` of Awaitility, and it is not working out. I understand Awaitility is for async behavior and `until` function is a big part of it. I'm hoping someone with more experience with Awaitility could suggest a clean usage of it in this test scenario, much appreciate your input.

```java
//Thread.sleep(1000);
Awaitility.await().atMost(Duration.ONE_SECOND);
list = client.getLocation();
Assertions.assertFalse(list.isEmpty());
```

Comment: If you don’t want to use `until` you might as well use `sleep`.

Comment: Boris the Spider beat me to it: Q: If you've got a bunch of code that uses Thread.sleep() ... and if Thread.Sleep works ... then why do you want to change to Awaitility.await()??? What's your motivation/what are the benefits?  PS: You might also want to consider these alternatives: https://www.baeldung.com/java-delay-code-execution

Comment: @paulsm4  I'd like to replace it to satisfy Sonar rules.

Comment: Thank you for saying   HAPPY FRIDAY !!!

Comment: @KUTAYZORLU See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778/2886891, I have just removed the "HAPPY FRIDAY" :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Despite your intention, I encourage you to give Awaitility and `until()` another try. The example below test the same thing in a single one-liner (albeit it is written in several lines for improved readability):

```
@Test
void test_refresh() {
    Awaitility
       .await()
       .atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .until(() -> { 
           List<Trp> trpList = client.getAllTrps();
           return !trpList.isEmpty();
       });
}
```

For more fine grained control of the polling you can take a look at methods like [pollInterval()](https://javadoc.io/static/org.awaitility/awaitility/4.1.0/org/awaitility/core/ConditionFactory.html#pollInterval-java.time.Duration-) and [pollDelay()](https://javadoc.io/static/org.awaitility/awaitility/4.1.0/org/awaitility/core/ConditionFactory.html#pollDelay-java.time.Duration-).

Comment: Per the OP's update, this appears to be an [XYProblem](https://xyproblem.info/).  The problem isn't really "Thread.sleep()", and the solution isn't necessarily "Awaitility.await()".  The *REAL* problem is that Sonar is complaining about "Thread.sleep()".

Comment: I love your solution, it also addresses the for loop, thank you very much for the input, I very much appreciate it.

Comment: @paulsm4 thanks for your comment. I guess that this is this sonar warning that causes the problem: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2925 , it mentions `Awaitility.await().atMost().until()` as a possible solution.

Answer (score 6):

Though what you did can make sense from the first look, but with a better understanding of the design of the library there are two apparent principles that you have missed.

The Awaitility library introduces a functional style usage to define properties, conditions, accumulators and transformations.

#### 1. Terminal Operations.

---

```java
  Awaitility
       .await()
       .atMost(Duration.TWO_SECONDS)
```

The above code will not execute, because internally what runs the chain is a call to `Condition#await` which is accessed only by caling `ConditionFactory#until`.

> This call to `until`  can be called a `Terminal Operation`

#### 2. Intermediate Operations.

---

Operations like `await`, `atMost` , `timeout` and other operations only return the same instance of `ConditionFactory`, which will only define behaviour and actions in a **lazy** manner.

So in a nutshell the design expects you to:

1. Create an instance of `ConditionFactory` using `Awaitility#await`.
2. Define your await behaviour using the intermediate methods.
3. Execute and/or transform using `until` and its variants.

Answer (score 3):

A simple replacement with Awaitility for:

```java
Thread.sleep(200);
```

could be:

```java
Awaitility.await()
      .pollDelay(Duration.ofMillis(200))
      .until(() -> true);
```